# Optaplanner ideas to escape local minima

Tags: optaplanner

I have an Optaplanner problem where I can't seem to figure out how to escape local minima.  I'm using Optaplanner to schedule soccer leagues.  One of the constraints is that each team must play exactly once per week.  I have a constraint that penalizes a team playing multiple games in the same week.  My problem is the optimization has a hard time finding *any* solution as any swap/change of games usually just produces different double headers that break the constraint.  As a workaround, I've written a construction heuristic that builds a solution with few enough double headers that Optaplanner can easily find a solution.  However, with that approach, the optimization rarely leaves that local minima to satisfy other scheduling constraints.  This is using tabu as it seems to do the best job.

The model is fairly simple.  The optimization problem is to schedule each "Event" to a "LocationSlot".  All events are pre-defined with the 2 teams playing.  All location slots are predefined with a location and a date/time range.

```
@PlanningSolution
public class ScheduleSolution {

    @ConstraintConfigurationProvider
    private ScheduleConstraintConfiguration constraintConfiguration;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<LocationSlot> slots = new ArrayList<LocationSlot>();

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private Set<Participant> participants = new TreeSet<Participant>();

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score = null;

    ...
}
```

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Event {

    @PlanningId
    private long id;

    private EventType eventType;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "slotRange")
    private LocationSlot slot;
    ...

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "slotRange")
    public Set<LocationSlot> getSlotRange() {
        return eventType.getCompatibleSlots();
    }

}
```

```
public class EventType implements Comparable<EventType> {

    private String name;
    private Set<LocationSlot> compatibleSlots = new HashSet<LocationSlot>();
    ...
}
```

```
public class LocationSlot {

    @PlanningId
    private long id;

    private Location location;
    private DateTimeRange timeRange;
    ...
}
```

```
public class DateTimeRange implements Comparable<DateTimeRange> {

    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;

    ...
}
```

From what I've read, it seems likely that I need either/both a new constraint to guide the solver or a coarse-grained move to shake things up?  Is that true?  Any suggestions on what those might look like?

Comment: How did you model your problem, what are the planning entitites, and planning variable ? Maybe also look here to see if there is an example that fits your usecase: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added some code to go along with the description of the model in the question.  Also, this is modeled loosely after the conferencescheduling example from the link you provided.

Comment: Coarse grained moves would definitely help, but I am thinking that in this case move filters may be more useful. That will prevent searching in the infeasible space for a long time. E.g. if a team is already assigned a slot, prevent the assignment of any other slot in the same week. See here: https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.30.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#filteredSelection

Comment: The challenge is that there are other constraints to be considered as well.  For example, some teams cannot play at certain times during the day.  I wonder if the solution is to define a move filter and union it with the more generic change and swap moves to control the frequency of the selected moves.

Comment: Yup, you could create a move filter for the`changeMove` or `swapMove`s and union with the non-filtered ones. Try to see if that works ?